# FileReader should complete onload function first then process further

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise

I want to read the uploaded file and send those contents inside file via service API Call. But Onload function executes at last.I want onload function to be executed first then only move to further steps

```
checkInScript(file: File, scriptName: string): Observable<Response>{
    console.log("****Before Calling Method***");
    this.checkValidFile(file).then((value) => {
      console.log("****value****",value);
      this.fileValue.next(value);
    })
    console.log("****After Calling method***");
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('updateScript', this.fileValue.value);
    console.log("****Form Data***");
    return this.http.post(this.mccScriptOperationURL  + '/updateScript/' + scriptName, formData);
  }

  checkValidFile(file: File): Promise<string>{
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        console.log("****Inside on Load*****");
        resolve(fileReader.result.toString());
      };
    });
  }
```

Current Execution pattern is :
****Before Calling Method*****
****After Calling method*****
****Form Data*****
****Inside on Load*****
****value****

Required Execution Pattern is:
****Before Calling Method*****
****Inside on Load*****
****value*****
****After Calling method*****
****Form Data****`

Comment: only code inside `.then(....` will *wait* for the promise returned by `checkValidFile` to resolve - consider using async/await for easier to read code, but still, you need to understand asynchrony in general

Comment: Yes But I need data inside file to pass data to FormData. As of now its returning null from BehaviorSubject

Comment: exactly my point, and your code is clearly NOT doing that ... consider putting all the code `console.log("****After Calling method***"); ..... return this.http.post(.... etc` INSIDE the `.then` - because inside the `.then` is where the promise is resolved and thus you have waited for `checkValidFile` to complete - that's how asynchrony works ... as for `As of now its returning null from BehaviorSubject` what even is "BehaviourSubject" - it's not mentioned in the code at all

Comment: But If use all this inside .then() I need to return observable<response> from API but then it will give compilation error.

Comment: yes, that's an issue with asynchronous code - returning from a function that deals with Promises, usually means returning a Promise - I'm not very familiar with "Observable" though, so ...

Comment: Note that you don't need that FileReader at all, `Blob` (and thus `File`)  objects have a `.text()` method which will read their content as UTF-8 and return a Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was earlier going to suggest the same method as @JaromandaX but then realized the null problem that would create. I think `await`ing the `checkValidFile` should work as expected, in the correct sequential order.

```js
async checkInScript(file: File, scriptName: string): Observable < Response > {
  console.log("****Before Calling Method***");
  const value = await this.checkValidFile(file);

  console.log("****value****", value);
  this.fileValue.next(value);

  console.log("****After Calling method***");
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('updateScript', this.fileValue.value);

  console.log("****Form Data***");
  return this.http.post(this.mccScriptOperationURL + '/updateScript/' + scriptName, formData);
}

checkValidFile(file: File): Promise < string > {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(file);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      console.log("****Inside on Load*****");
      resolve(fileReader.result.toString());
    };
  });
}
```